# Does the auto factory reset reset the counting of 15 wrong attempts?

Tags: settings, lock-screens, factory-reset

I just set up a PIN to my device when I saw the option of enabling auto factory reset after 15 wrong attempts to unlock my phone and I now wonder: for how long are these 15 attempts valid? One hour? Day? Ever?

Comment: I do not think it would make sense to take an action if the failed attempts are not consecutive (no successful login in between, that is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failed unlock counter will reset when the device is successfully unlocked.

Comment: I won't try it myself, but it makes sense and I don't know how I didn't realize it. Thanks.